# Order relation in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: order-theory

I'm with trouble with this question: verify that the relation given by $$xRy \iff \exists n \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ such that } x = y + n$$ is an order relation in $\mathbb{Q}$

My doubt is in the part of antisymmetry, because how can I get from the equations

$x = y + n$ and

$y = x + m$

That x = y? I don't see this happening, so I think this is not an order relation. Is this right?

Comment: Obviously $0R1$ and $1R0$ but $0\ne 1$, so no, it's not an order relation.

Comment: That relation is not an order relation. It is also not “in $\mathbb Q,$” unless it is trivial. Also, you haven’t told us what you want us to prove about the relation. Prove that the relation given by X is what?

Comment: It's an equivalence relation, not an order relation.

Comment: Your question is incomplete, may be that's the problem: "verify that the relation given by ... " **is an order relation**? Or me be **is an equivalence relation**? You didn't specify WHAT are you supposed to verify about the relation.

Comment: @jjagmath you're right, I forgot to complete. But I'm supposed to verify if this is an order relation

Comment: Well, it's not.

Comment: Is $n$ required to be positive?  If not, this obviously isn’t an order relation.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P:xRy$ and $Q:yRx$. By the order axioms you must have
$$ P\wedge Q\implies \{x=y\}$$
by negation
$$ x\neq y\implies \bar{P}\vee\bar{Q}$$
Meaning that if $x$ is different than $y$, one of them at least must not be in a relation with the other.

But for instance, if you take $x=1$, and $y=-1$, you can find $n=2\in \mathbb Q$ such that $1=-1+2$. Same applies the other way, you can find $n=-2\in\mathbb Q$. Which is a contradiction as at least one of $\bar{P}$ and $\bar{Q}$ must be verified.

So the relation is not an order relation